# Undefined function 'fittype' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

```
TE = [75 300];
Box = [134:200, 164:200, 15];
T1 = Image1(134:200,164:200,15);
T2 =Image2(134:200,164:200,15);

figure(1);
hold on;
plot(TE,[mean2(T1),mean2(T2)],'.')

% plot(TE,cell2mat(gemiddelde_pixelwaarde),'.')
title('T2 MAP');
       
g = fittype({'a*b*exp(-x/T2)','1'});

f = fit(TE',cell2mat([mean2(T1),mean2(T2)])',g,'StartPoint',[30 10 20]);
return
```

I get an error from the `fittype` and don't know exactly what it means and what to do.

Comment: Do you have "curve fitting toolbox"? try to type "which fittype"

Comment: Yes, I got the toolbox now. 
This is the error it to ''' Error using fittype>iAssertNotMember (line 1103)
Coefficient 'a' appears in a linear term.
Try creating equation as a general (nonlinear) equation instead.

Comment: You should not include the coefficients. Try `g = fittype({'exp(-x/T2)','1'});`